# удаление элемента выпадающего списка jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Бьюсь лбом об стену уже не первый час. Спасите пожалуйста мою психику!

Суть проблемы:

На странице есть `<ul class="dropdown-menu">` который появляется при нажатии на кнопку. Содержимое этого элемента добавляется динамически `<li>` элементы, с помощью ajax. Как мне затем удалить эти `<li>` используя jquery.

Я использую такой код, но это не работает

```
function deleteNotify(key){
    $.ajax({
        url:defaultPath+'notifyCenter/deleteNotify/'+key,
        success:function(){
            $('.myLi').remove();
        }
    });
}
```

P.S: эта функция вызывается при нажатии кнопки. Запрос отрабатывает успешно, а элемент не находит

Comment: ваш элемент содержит этот класс `.myLI`?

Comment: если вы хотите очистить содержимое списка, то у вас должно быть что то вида `<ul class="my-dd-list"`>...` и вызов вида `$(".my-dd-list").empty()`

Comment: либо `<ul><li class="myLi"></li><li class="myLi">....</ul>`, тогда да `$('.myLi').remove();`

Comment: <ul><li class="myLi"></li><li class="myLi">....</ul> структура такова.

Comment: Ошибка: элемент не найден. Я думаю, что это происходит из-за того, что я заполняю список динамически с помощью ajax

Comment: НО как это фиксануть???

Comment: Вам нужно удалить все элементы или один только? Если один конкретный, то он должен иметь уникальный класс или id. Вы же пытаетесь удалить элемент с классом, повторяющимся у других элементов.

Comment: дело в том что я сначала хотел удалить конкретный элемент списка: добавлял ему id и пытался удалять по id, но элемент не находился(

Comment: функция, написанная мною выше, находится за пределами  $( document ).ready

Comment: Уникальный id вам необходимо добавить в любом случае, а видимость элемента просто проверьте по его id так: `console.log($('#newLi').length);`

Comment: @118_64 Уникальный id в данном случае не играет роли.

Comment: @АлексейМидиницин проверьте что элементы действительно существуют, что селектор `$('.myLi')` написан верно, и возвращает то что нужно. Ну и убедится что `success` вызывается. Т.к. то что вы указали, работает исправно (https://jsfiddle.net/vdz1hwrz/)